# Get average daily total in grafana

Tags: prometheus, grafana

I have an instant metric (let's call it `foo`) in grafana, and trying to find an average daily total over a time range.

I think, I can do daily totals like this:

```
sum(sum_over_time(foo{bar="baz"}[1d])
```

That gives me a chart like this:
[image]

How do I get the average value over this time interval?
I am trying

```
avg_over_time(sum(sum_over_time(foo{bar="baz"}[1d])))
```

This says `expected type range vector in call to function "avg_over_time", got instant vector`
Ok, make sense. So, I try to turn it into a range vector:

```
avg_over_time(sum(sum_over_time(foo{bar="baz"}[1d]))[30d])
```

and get `ranges only allowed for vector selectors`

This is where I get lost: didn't it just tell me, it *was* an (instant) vector? And now it seems to be saying that it is not?

Answer (score 0):

#### For range of dashboard:

The easiest way: enable legend in your time series panel options, and select `mean` in values.

If you want same as independent panel: create Stat panel with same query. Value options > Calculation > Mean.

#### For fixed range:

You could use

```
sum_over_time( foo [30d] @end()) / 30
```

This will sum values of your metric for 30 days preceding dashboard end timestamp and divide it by 30.